# Office 365 SMTP authentication via XOAUTH2

Tags: oauth-2.0, oauth, smtp, office365

I'm following this guide https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/exchange/client-developer/legacy-protocols/how-to-authenticate-an-imap-pop-smtp-application-by-using-oauth and here's all the steps I've taken -

Note: I'm not posting my actual client id's, codes or secrets.

**Step 1**: Register an Azure app.

Account type: Accounts in this organizational directory only

Redirect URI: http://localhost (Web)

Created a client secret

Added SMTP.Send API permission

**Step 2**: Request an authorization code

```
https://login.microsoftonline.com/organizations/oauth2/v2.0/authorize?
client_id=6731de76-14a6-49ae-97bc-6eba6914391e
&response_type=code
&redirect_uri=http://localhost
&response_mode=query
&scope=https://outlook.office.com/SMTP.Send
```

**Step 3**: Redeem the authorization code (!!! 793 characters long) for an access token using the client secret

```
curl -d "client_id=6731de76-14a6-49ae-97bc-6eba6914391e
&scope=https://outlook.office.com/SMTP.Send
&code=OAAABAAAAiL9Kn2Z27UubvWFPbm0gLWQJVzCTE9UkP3pSx1aXxUjq3n8b2JRLk4OxVXr...
&redirect_uri=http://localhost
&grant_type=authorization_code
&client_secret=JqQX2PNo9bpM0uEihUPzyrh" -X POST https://login.microsoftonline.com/organizations/oauth2/v2.0/token
```

**Step 4**: Convert the mailbox username and bearer token (!!! 1787 characters long) into a base64 string

```
echo -n "user=test@contoso.onmicrosoft.com^Aauth=Bearer EwBAAl3BAAUFFpUAo7J3Ve0bjLBWZWCclRC3EoAA^A^A" | base64
```

**The final base64 string is 2464 characters long and obviously WAY too long for SMTP to accept. Where am I going wrong with this?**

Answer (score 2):

I found this online that MS has not enabled OAuth for SMTP from the documentation [Link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/exchange/client-developer/legacy-protocols/how-to-authenticate-an-imap-pop-smtp-application-by-using-oauth#smtp-protocol-exchange)

Basic Auth still works for SMTP and will be disabled for IMAP AND POP protocols.
Please reply if you have figured out a way to use OAuth for SMTP to send mails.

Comment: Yes, thats what I heard too. Except for SMTP all other mediums (IMAP, POP) will not be on Basic Authentication. However, Microsoft have not said specifically and different views says otherwise. Couldn't get onto comfort yet :(